# Quotes not rendering properly in javascript in mvc view

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have a script tag like below in my partial view :

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/ChartsAPI/2",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (seriesData) {

            console.log(seriesData);

            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                dataSource: {
                    data: seriesData
                },
                series: [{
                    field: "yaxisData",
                    name: "Average"
                }],
                title:
                   { @ViewBag.PlaceHolder }
            });
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

In my controller the view bag data is populated like below :

```
ViewBag.PlaceHolder = "text:'test'";
```

But with this configuration, the chart is not getting rendered correctly as the chart text for the title is being rendered as below :

```
text:&#39;test&#39;
```

How to get rid of the ascii for the qutoes in javascript.

Comment: wrapit it with a span or div element

Comment: like this ViewBag.PlaceHolder = "text:'test'";  ViewBag.PlaceHolder  = "<div>"+ ViewBag.PlaceHolder +"</div>"

Comment: i cannot wrap with a span or a div, as the text is a sub property of the main title property of the chart.